# Calculate costs from purchases with variant prices

Tags: mysql

Imagine you have a shop and a stock. You are purchasing products for different prices and want to calculate the costs for every sale. The problem is that the purchase-prices are not fix and you might have sales where you are selling items from different purchases with mixed purchase-prices. The costs should be calculated in a kind of "first in first out"-principle: You are selling the oldest items on stock first.

So for example this might happen:

- 2018-10-01: You are buying 6 items of "Product1" for $10.00 each and put them into your stock.
- 2018-10-04: A customer wants 2 items of "Product1". You will go into your stock and sell 2 items which you bought for $10.00 each.
- 2018-11-01: You are buying 8 items of "Product1" for $8.00 each and put them into your stock.
- 2018-11-06: A customer wants 7 items of "Product1". You will go into your stock and sell 4 items which you bought for $10.00 each and 3 items which you bought for $8.00 each.
- 2018-12-01: You are buying 4 items of "Product1" for $12.00 each.
- 2018-12-10: A customer wants 6 items of "Product1". You will go into your stock and sell 5 items which you bought for $8.00 each and 1 item which you bought for $12.00.

So trying to put this in 2 tables:

table: purchases

```
purchase | product | amount | purchase price per item|       date |
      1          1        6                     10.00   2018-10-01
      2          1        8                      8.00   2018-11-01
      3          1        4                     12.00   2018-12-01
```

table: sales

```
sale | product | amount |      date | costs
   1         1        2   2018-10-04     ??
   2         1        7   2018-11-06     ??
   3         1        6   2018-12-10     ??
```

The values in sales.costs should be:

```
Sale 1: 2*10.00 = 20.00
Sale 2: 4*10.00 + 3*8.00 = 64.00
Sale 3: 5*8.00 + 1*12.00 = 52.00
```

Any ideas if/how it might be possible to calculate this in MySql 5.6 with an UPDATE-statement? I have to admit I haven't even got an idea how to start here or what to try.

Comment: The calculation have to be done in pure MySQL? No PHP, C++, Javascript or so on?

Answer (score 1):

First of all i add a new Table called `stock`. Inside this table I store every change in stock. It looks like this:

```
purchase | sold |       date |
       1 |    2 | 2018-10-04 |
       1 |    4 | 2018-11-06 |
       2 |    3 | 2018-11-06 |
       2 |    5 | 2018-12-10 |
       3 |    1 | 2018-12-10 |
```

You can fill this table with a `TRIGGER` if you want or by hand.
Now I use this script:

```
SET @toSell:=5;
SELECT s.stock, p.price, LEAST( s.stock, @toSell ) AS toSell , @toSell * p.price AS totalPrice, @toSell := @toSell - LEAST( s.stock, @toSell ) AS stillNeeded
FROM (
    SELECT p.purchase, SUM( s.sold ) AS  'sold', p.amount, IFNULL( p.amount - SUM( s.sold ) , p.amount ) AS  'stock'
    FROM purchases AS p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stock AS s ON p.purchase = s.purchase
    GROUP BY p.purchase
    ORDER BY p.date
) AS s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN purchases AS p ON s.purchase = p.purchase
WHERE s.stock >0 AND LEAST( s.stock, @toSell ) > 0;
```

To calculate the cost for every sale. At the beginning I define a variable containing the amount of items to sell. This Variable will be manipulated in every row. The inner `SELECT` is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get the amount of items inside the stock of every purchase ordered by date to use the oldest items first (FIFO).

The Second `SELECT` use now the stock items and reduce the variable row by row until no more items where needed. You simply have to `SUM` the `totalPrice` column to get the costs.

To Test the script i add a new row/purchase

```
purchase | product | amount | purchase price per item|       date |
       4 |       1 |     10 |                      5 | 2019-02-04 |
```

When you run this script with `SET @toSell:=2` the result will look this way:

```
stock | price | toSell | totalPrice | stillNeeded |
    3 |    12 |      2 |         24 |           0 |
```

And with `SET @toSell:=5`

```
stock | price | toSell | totalPrice | stillNeeded |
    3 |    12 |      3 |         60 |           2 |
   10 |     5 |      2 |         10 |           0 |
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I need some time to test this and get back to you.